# Как правильно работать с asp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, serial

Есть код, создаю контроллер, а не понимаю как вывести его во view. Помогите

```
using System;
```

using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Web.Http;

public class SerialPortController : ApiController
{
private SerialPort _serialPort;

```
public SerialPortController()
{
    _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600); // Укажите нужный порт и скорость передачи
    _serialPort.Open();
}

[HttpGet]
public string ReadDataFromSerialPort()
{
    string data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
    return data;
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        _serialPort.Close();
        _serialPort.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

}

Comment: Будьте точны в формулировках. Вам нужно вывести не _контроллер_, а какие-то _данные_. / Эти данные меняются редко или они идут сплошным быстроизменяющимся потоком? В первом случае стандартная вьюха. Во втором случае нужен js на странице, который будет в цикле запрашивать новые данные (или получать по вебсокету).

Comment: Кстати, mvc и web-api - разные технологии. Вы уж определитесь, что используете.